# How to find if IDE devices running on a Ubuntu 20.04 server and also if the required IDE kernel module loaded

Tags: server

How to verify if IDE is any IDE devices running on Ubuntu20.04 .
Also how to check if the required IDE kernel module loaded ?

Comment: Look at the names of the devices. If you have and `/dev/hd*` devices, they’re probably IDE. [Dell has a helpful document](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/ja-jp/000132092/ubuntu-linux-terms-for-your-hard-drive-and-devices-explained) explaining device naming conventions 

Comment: Thanks .. helps @matigo